# Limit GridSplitter (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gridsplitter

Simple case, when I want to limit `GridSplitter` maximum, then I can create *invisible* control (which only participates in layouting), adjust its `Margin` and use to limit grid column/row definitions:

```
<Grid x:Name="limiter" Margin="10,10,20,10" />
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding StoreWidth, Converter={local:DoubleToGridLengthConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
             MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=gridLimit}" /> <!-- limit maximum -->
    ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter ... />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Now complicated case: nested view with `GridSplitter`, which has to be limited by some layout logic of parent view.

How do I do this? I am seeking for a *comfortable* and reusable solution.

Currently I am doing it *complicated* way:

- add property to parent VM to bind `limiter` values (e.g. `ActualWidth` of it);
- add to nested VM property `Parent`;
- pass parent VM instance to nested one (using property initializer);
- now `GridSplitter` can be limited by using `Parent.SplitterMaxWidth` binding.

Is there any nice and MVVM-friendly approach to the problem?

Comment: I'd rather think about using Behavior instead of VM. In my opinion ViewModels shouldn't have such things like ActualWidth. They should contain Model logic, not Presentation logic.

Comment: @mikes, I agree. How exactly I could do it with behavior? You see problem: the width/height is measured in one view and the value has to be used in other view. This indeed some kind of view-to-view communications (would be nice to don't have VM in-between). Sometimes it is possible to bind with `FindAncestor`, but in my case `GridSplitter` is never that easy (`limiter` is not parent of it).

Comment: How are the Views separated from each other? Are they inside a common View? For example, the left view controls the right view parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For cases when `GridSplitter` has to be limited by parent (TBH all my layouts can be converted to ensure this) it is possible to bind to that parent and use generic converter to change value. If parent is hard to reach, then make a simple custom control:

```
public class GridLimiter: Grid { }
```

which can be used to *mark* that container to be easily reached by `RelativeSource.FindAncestor`:

```
<local:GridLimiter ... >
    ... <!-- deeply nested -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GridLimiter}}}" />
            ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter ... />
    </Grid>
    ...
```

Moreover, making a simple markup extension converter:

```
public class ValueAddConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public ValueAddConverter() { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (double)value + double.Parse((string)parameter, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

allows to define offset without needs to create *invisible* limiter:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={local:ValueAddConverter}, ConverterParameter=-30, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GridLimiter}}}"
```